# Why hta script doesn't run from internet explorer menu item?

Tags: internet-explorer, customization, hta

I created this hta file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("alert!!!");
</script>
```

And added menu item in IE (like described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753591(v=vs.85).aspx) to run it. I see my menu item in ie, script value in my menu item's registry key points to my hta file. So why when I press menu item nothing happens(I see no alert). Please help me to debug it.

Comment: Didn't HTAs die in IE6 or something? I'm not sure though.

Comment: I just want to add item to ie menu. To open my link in new tab or window. I want to know how to do it without creating com ole or something.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I suppose `Script` file should be `.js` or maybe `.wsf` instead of `.hta`. @Pekka HTAs are still alive, and somehow work even with IE10 : ).

Answer (score 1):

I changed file extension from hta to htm and it started working. )))

Comment: Interesting. Can you now refer to `document` just using `document`, or is the Yecril's hack needed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, at the end of the MSDN page there are some instructions by yecril. Yecril says, that the `document` is not available as it normally would. `document` should be referred via `external.menuArguments`, which actually seems to represent the current `window` object.

`alert()` is a method of `window`, so I suppose your script should be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var win = external.menuArguments;
    win.alert("alert!!!");
</script>
```

---

(I know this is pure speculation and should be rather a comment, but I found this being too broad for a comment.)

Comment: Actually I changed file extension from hta to htm and it started to work.